# Nifi move files with another name

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to move the processed files from source location to loaded directory with the name of filename.done.

I used fetchsftp processor ad its moving the files with same name but i want to rename the files as well.

Please suggest me any other procssor in NiFi.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: after fetchsftp (with delete file) - use PutSFTP (with new file name)

Comment: Thanks but what will happen if putsftp unable to drop the files into local directory  but fetchsftp was delete the files?

Comment: what do you mean by "drop the files into local directory" ? store into nifi queue ?

Comment: do not drop the file in failure and make a loop there for failure events, so it will be in the queue if not stored in local directory

Comment: Got it thank you do much